# Require User Login for using Bot Framework and AAD OAuth2

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework

I have a bot written in .NET using the BotBuilder SDK from Microsoft, and am currently authenticating users using Azure Active Directory and the OAuthPrompt. My problem arises when I want to allow the user to switch credentials - even when I sign the user out and try to log back in, clicking the sign in button will automatically authenticate the user and send them back to the bot with a valid token.

I was thinking this might be something to do with the cache, but my bot lives on Teams and I don't want to have to figure out how to clear Teams cache every time I logout a user. I've seen that using `prompt=login` as a parameter to my login request is a solution, but because all of the actual requests are abstracted away by the OAuthPrompt, there is no place to add that option. Are there any solutions to force user login while using the BotBuilder framework?

Comment: Yes, `prompt=login` is the solution for this scenario. Are you still facing any issue?

Comment: I don't know where to put that option - as I said, the actual uri request is abstracted by the OAuthPrompt

Answer (score 0):

This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/oauthprompt?view=botbuilder-ts-latest) will help you to use OAuthPrompt.

```
dialogs.add(new OAuthPrompt('loginPrompt', {
   connectionName: 'GitConnection',
   title: 'Login To GitHub',
   timeout: OAuthLoginTimeoutMsValue   // User has 15 minutes to login
}));
```